# github schedule action never gets triggered

Tags: github-actions

I have the following workflow, but it never gets triggered. I have spent time on github documentation, but can't seem to find what I am doing wrong

```
name: my-cron

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '*/1 * * * *'

jobs:
  myCron:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: run a one-line script
        run: echo Hello, world
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is it committed to the default (usually `master`) branch?

Comment: yes it is commited to the default branch, and I also tried to change event from schedul to push and it works; it's just for schedule that doesn't trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The shortest interval you can run scheduled workflows is once every 5 minutes.

From the [documentation here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#scheduled-events-schedule).

So try every 5 minutes instead of every minute.

```
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '*/5 * * * *'
```